# Did Chrome max_old_space_size parameter stop working?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Some years ago, it was possible to start Chrome or Chromium based application with a `--js-flags="--max_old_space_size=8196"` parameter and pass beyond the default 2GB or 4GB heap limit. For example:

```
chrome.exe --js-flags="--max_old_space_size=8196"
```

But in recent builds (Chrome 111), this doesn't seem to be working anymore. Did something change?

Here is a screenshot how this was validated before using the DevTools Performance Monitor:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it was removed see https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/174889666/increasing-the-memory-limit-on-chrome-v104

Comment: @BlindSpots Thank you, it does seem like it was removed, but not in build 103. I downloaded previous versions of Chromium, and I the last build that supports `--js-flags="--max_old_space_size=8196"` is Chromium 79 as Jogy mentions here: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=18306#p48666